# Удаление более двух пустых строк

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

```
$preg = preg_replace("/([\n\n])+/s", "\n\n", $preg);
```

Есть такая регулярка. Нужно найти, если есть, 2+ пустых строк новых строк и заменить количество пустых строк до 2. Подскажите, почему данная регулярка не работает, то есть есть 10 идущих друг за другом пустых строк, он их не сокращает до 2.

Answer (score 1):

Ключ другой

```
  $preg = preg_replace("/([\n\n])+/m", "\n\n", $preg);
```

Хотя само регулярное выражение странное. Скорее

```
  $preg = preg_replace("/\n{3,}/m", "\n\n", $preg);
```

Comment: $preg = preg_replace("/\n{3,}/m", "\n\n", $preg);
не помогло

Comment: "А не будет ли милостивый джин" ((c) м/ф "Барон Мюнхгаузен") рассказать о проблеме немного поподробнее?

У меня.

    <hmtl>
    <title>php</title>
    <body>
    <?php $preg="ddddddddddd\n\n\n\n\nffffffffffff\n\n\nlll"; 
    $preg = preg_replace("/\n{3,}/m", "\n\n", $preg);
    echo $preg; ?>
    </body> </html>

переводы строк подстригает. Правда в отрендеренной страничке в браузере этого не видно (только в виде html), но это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: Наверно лучше будет так:  

    preg_replace("/(?:\r?\n){3,}/m", "\n\n", $preg);
Чтобы была поддержка как Unix, так и Windows строк.